# How to automatically delete rows that contain certain numbers in the ID column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a column of numbers in another workbook and I would like to use that set of numbers to delete rows in the main workbook. I will give an simplified example of what I'm talking about below. My case over a thousand unique numbers.

Can I use conditional formatting or `LOOKUP` to delete the rows from the main workbook?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the match function to see if the number is in your list.  If the match function doesn't find an exact match it returns a n/a.  Using this fact we can flag cells as either being in the list or not.  Once you have a flag filter the rows and delete all the ones that are in your list.

> =IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2,$F$2:$F$3,0)),"Not in List","In list")

Comment: Thanks this worked like a charm. I used a VBA script to remove all entries that had In List in the cell. Now would I used the lookup function if I wanted to use two pieces of data in the master sheet to get a corresponding piece of data from the secondary sheet?

Comment: Rather then use a vba script it is usually just easier to filter or sort in place and delete the rows manually.  As for using two pieces of data to look something up there are many ways to do just google a double lookup or double match.  I like using index+match but it depends on how your data is setup and what you are trying to return (number or string)

Comment: Im trying to return a number. But thanks for your help, would a conditional formatting be easier than a vba script for the first task?

Comment: Personally I would just select the table click Filter in the ribbon and filter to show everything you don't want select all the rows right click delete, delete entire row.

Comment: Ahh, yea that sounds a whole lot simpler than what I used. Hey thanks again for your help with the formula!

Comment: Hey I used =INDEX(sheet2!$C2:$C$4835,MATCH($A2&$D2,sheet2!$D$2:$D$4835&sheet2!$N$2:$N$4835,0))   This worked for a majority of the rows but Im getting a #REF! for the rest

Comment: the row of your first C2 reference isn't locked (no $ in front of it).  This means your index array is getting smaller as it is dragged down.  If the index array is only 5 cells long and the match function returns a higher number this will cause a ref error